# How to match each row and column of dataframe against a string - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a string and a dataframe below:

```
s = """Econsult :
IHD/ DM/ HTN
Suggest
Tablet augmentin duo 625mg 1-0-1 for 3 days after breakfast and after dinner
Capsule providac 1-0-1 for 3 days after breakfast and after dinner
Tablet pantodac 40mg 1-0-0 for 3 days before breakfast
Monday
Decide based on reports
Thanks"""
```

df =

```
   |  col1         | synonnym1      |synonym2
    ------------------------------------------
   | Diabetes      | DM             |Diabetes Mellitus
    -----------------------------------------
   | Hear failure  | Congestive     |NaN
   |               | heart failure  |
   -------------------------------------------
   | Hypertension  |  HTN           | HBP
```

As you can see in the string I have a word "DM" and in the second column of dataframe I have the word "DM".
I want to loop every element of the dataframe such that it matches in the string and return me the row of that dataframe, In this case, DM matched, so I would expect (Diabetes, DM, Diabetes Mellitus) in return. Similarly, HBP could be matched next time, so it will return (Hypertension, HTN, HBP).

I tried

```
data['res'] = data.apply( lambda col:col.str.contains('|'.join(str('a')))).any(axis=1)
result = data[data['res']==True]
```

but this will match input string to the dataframe. I want  every element of the dataframe is matched to the input string and return me row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `pd.DataFrame.applymap`:

```
new_df = df[df.applymap(lambda x: x in s).any(1)]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
           col1 synonnym1           synonym2
0      Diabetes        DM  Diabetes Mellitus
2  Hypertension       HTN                HBP
```